# Drill down using HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I've created an HTML Document using

```
           Dim htmlDoc = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
```

and have a node

```
         node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/main/section/form[1]/input[2]")
```

and the OuterHtml is

```
         "<input type="hidden" id="public-id" value="michael.smith.1">"
```

I need the value of michael.smith.1.  Is there a way to pull the value property from the node or am I at the point where I use substring to parse out the value?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `id` firstly as this makes for faster matching, then use the [`GetAttributeValue`](https://documentation.help/HtmlAgilityPack/9461433a-89d3-6c49-89ec-a5d522676c21.htm) method of [`HtmlNode`](https://documentation.help/HtmlAgilityPack/cc80368c-8bdc-efc0-a686-d7889b607b29.htm) to extract the `value` attribute

```
Imports System
Imports HtmlAgilityPack

Public Class Program
    Public Shared Sub Main()   
        Dim doc = new HtmlDocument
        Dim output As String = "<html><head><title>Text</title></head><body><input type=""hidden"" id=""public-id"" value=""michael.smith.1""></body></html>"
        
        doc.LoadHtml(output)
        Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='public-id']").GetAttributeValue("value","Not present"))
        
    End Sub
    
End Class
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/R7wZ3B)